# What does the moon icon on a challenge mean?

Tags: sonic-frontiers

Challenge M-015 has a yellow moon icon with a star on it. What does the moon icon mean?

[image: Challenge with a moon icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to IGN](https://www.ign.com/wikis/sonic-frontiers/Day/Night_Cycle), challenges with a crescent moon icon can only be completed at night. I verified this myself as I was only able to complete M-015 during the night.